# Server send message to all connected clients

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I know this question has been asked before, and I've tried the different solutions, but I got stuck in the implementation part.. :(

Currently multiple clients can connect to the server, I used the multithreaded KnockKnock server/client example from javadocs, and edited it slightly so that you can just send messages to the server, and it will echo them back to you, but I want to be able to make it so that if client 1 sends a message, then the server will broadcast them back to all the clients connected to the server.

I've tried looking around and saw people in the same position as I am in now, and they were told to make a list to keep track of all the connections, and then iterate through the list and send the message, but I really don't know in which class to put it or how to handle it.

If someone could show me or just give me hints to where I should start, it would be greatly appreciated, as I'm really just stuck at the moment :(

Here's where I'm at so far:

Server:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444)) {

            while (listening) {
                ServerThread thread = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept());
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " );
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }



}
```

ServerThread

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ServerThread extends Thread{



    private Socket socket = null;



    public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("MultiServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public void run() {

        try (
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            while (true) {


                String input = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(input);
                out.println("ecco " + input);



                if (input.equals("Bye"))
                    break;
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Client (not sure if necessary, but here is it anyways)

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        try (
                Socket kkSocket = new Socket("172.30.242.51", 4444);
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while (true) {

                if(in != null) {

                    String input = stdIn.readLine();
                    out.println("Client: " + input);
                    System.out.println(in.readLine());
                    out.flush();

                }

            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " );
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " );
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a nice weekend =)

Answer (score 0):

Operation 'write' is blocking in your example. So iterating by all connections can lead to delays and blocking your push thread. Also always set SO_TIMEOUT for socket if you do not want to have memory leaks.

I suggest using [netty server](http://netty.io/)

It has very nice functionality for pushing data to all connected clients - look for [ChannelGroup](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use NIO to solve this problem?

A simple example:

```
public class EchoServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Create TCP server channel
    ServerSocketChannel serv = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ServerSocket sock = serv.socket();

    //Create a socket on your IP and port (i.e: localhost:12345)
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(12345);

    //Bind server socket and socket address
    sock.bind(addr);

    //Configure socket so all its methods won't be blocking
    serv.configureBlocking(false);

    //Create a selector to attend all the incoming requests
    Selector selector = Selector.open();

    //Register into the selector the accept request type
    serv.register(selector,SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

    //Create a common buffer
    ByteBuffer commonBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
    commonBuffer.clear();

    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = null;
    ByteBuffer channelBuffer  = null;
    for (;;){ //Infinite loop

        System.out.println("Waiting for events......");
        selector.select(); // This call do is blocking

        System.out.println("New event received");

        it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) it.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("Processing %s", key));
            it.remove(); // Remove it to avoid duplications

            try{
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    System.out.println("Received new connection request");
                    processConnectionRequest(serv, selector);
                }else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    System.out.println("Received new reading request");
                    processReadingRequest(selector, commonBuffer, key);
                }else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    System.out.println("Received new writing request");
                    processWritingRequest(key);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                key.cancel();
                try {
                    key.channel().close();
                } catch (Exception ce) {}
            }//end catch
        }//end while
    }//end for
  }//end main

  private static void processWritingRequest(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel cli = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();

    System.out.println(String.format("Wrinting into the channel %s", cli));
    buf.flip();//prepare the buffer
    buf.rewind();
    cli.write(buf);

    if (buf.hasRemaining()) {
        //If there is more content remaining, compact the buffer    
        buf.compact();
    } else {
        buf.clear();
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
  }

  private static void processReadingRequest(Selector selector, ByteBuffer commonBuffer, SelectionKey key)
        throws IOException {
    SocketChannel cli = (SocketChannel) key.channel();


    if (cli.read(commonBuffer) == -1) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Closing channel %s", cli));
        cli.close(); // internally calls key.cancel()
    }
    else {//Send the data to all the channels

        commonBuffer.flip();//prepare the buffer
        Iterator<SelectionKey> it2 = selector.keys().iterator();
        System.out.println("Writing data to all the channels");
        SelectionKey keys = null;
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            keys = it2.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("Writing in %s", keys));

            ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) keys.attachment();

            if(buf!=null)
            {
            buf.put(commonBuffer);
            keys.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);

            commonBuffer.rewind();
            }

        }
        commonBuffer.clear();

    }
  }

  private static void processConnectionRequest(ServerSocketChannel serv, Selector selector)
        throws IOException, ClosedChannelException {
    ByteBuffer channelBuffer;
    SocketChannel cli = serv.accept();
    cli.configureBlocking(false);
    channelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(10000);
    System.out.println(String.format("Registering new reading channel: %s", cli));
    cli.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, channelBuffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this looks very confusing to me :(